# VB.NET need help in deserialization of a JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, steam

Hey I need help in deserializing this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "rgInventory": {
    "2722309060": {
      "id": "2722309060",
      "classid": "939801430",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 1
    },
    "2722173409": {
      "id": "2722173409",
      "classid": "937254203",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 2
    },
    "2721759518": {
      "id": "2721759518",
      "classid": "720293857",
      "instanceid": "188530139",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 3
    },
    "2721748390": {
      "id": "2721748390",
      "classid": "310777652",
      "instanceid": "480085569",
      "amount": "1",
      "pos": 4
    }
  }
}
```

at the end it should look like:

2722309060#2722173409#2721759518#2721748390

```
Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring) 'deserialize it
Dim tempfo As String = result("rgInventory").ToString 'get rgInventory
Console.WriteLine(tempfo)
```

how i can deserialize all 'id's?

Comment: No, there is much more data there than those Ids/keys.  Whats is the result of the code snippet?  How does it not work?  What is your actual question?

Comment: The question is how i can deserialize all 'id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json contains a Dictionary of items, the IDs you want are the keys. If you deserialized it, you could get them from the Dictionary. Otherwise, you can use `JParse` and linq to get them:

```vb
Dim jstr As String = ...
' parse the json
Dim js As JObject = JObject.Parse(jstr)

' extract the inventory items
Dim ji As JObject = JObject.Parse(js("rgInventory").ToString)
' get and store the keys
Dim theIds As List(Of String) = ji.Properties.Select(Function(k) k.Name).ToList()
```

I suspect that when `"success"` is false that the resulting items list will be empty.  Test that it works:

```vb
For Each s As String In theIds
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

Result:

> 2722309060
>   2722173409
>   2721759518
>   2721748390

Comment: Note that this doesnt actually deserialize the json (as per the title), it just extracts a few bits